# What does ({a,b}*)² mean?

Tags: formal-languages, notation

Pretty much just the title. Is it all possible combinations of a and b that have 2 letters ?

Comment: Probably means $\{a,b\}^*\cdot \{a,b\}^*$ where $\cdot$ is the concatenation operation for languages. In this case, its not hard to show that $(\{a,b\}^*)^2=\{a,b\}^*$.

Comment: It could also mean pairs of words from $\{a,b\}^*$, e.g., $(abba,baaa)$. Depends on the context.

Comment: Don't forget that the empty string,  $\epsilon$ is, for example, contained in $\{a,b\}^*$ so $(\{a,b\}^*)^2$ would also include $\epsilon, a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not a standard way to specify a regular or any other language, so any answer would be a guess. Most likely candidates:

```
A string in (a, b)*, followed by another string in (a, b)*

A string in (a, b)*, followed by the same string again.
```

Ask whoever gave this specification for a language.